# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wF_NKE/decorator/

Tags: python, pip

I'm running python on vscode on Ubuntu and I'm trying to install some Python modules like skimage. However when I do

```
pip install skimages
```

I just get this:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wF_NKE/decorator/
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

This means that your setuptools are out of date.

You can fix this by doing:

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: The same problem is still there even when I upgraded my setup-tools

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. I got around it by installing an older version decorator first.

```
pip install decorator==4.4.2
```